Uniform distribution over a triangle part 2
This post is a follow up of this first one and this second one.
Problem definition
Consider a triangle with vertices $V_1,V_2,V_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the following parametrization
\begin{equation*}
z=\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^3 \left[(V_{j+1}-V_j) \frac{L}{L_j} \left(\alpha-\frac{\tau_{j-1}}{L}\right)+V_j\right]1_{\left[\frac{\tau_{j-1}}{L},\frac{\tau_{j}}{L}\right)}(\alpha)}_{\triangleq \psi(\alpha)}
\end{equation*}
where

$V_4\triangleq V_1$
$L_j\triangleq \lVert V_{j+1}-V_j\rVert$ - i.e. the length of the $j$-th edge connecting $V_j$ and $V_{j+1}$
$\tau_0\triangleq 0$, $\tau_j\triangleq\sum_{i=1}^j L_i$
$L\triangleq \tau_n=\sum_{i=1}^n L_i$ - i.e. the length of the triangle perimeter
$1_S(x)=1$ if $x\in S$ and $1_S(x)=0$ otherwise. The factor $1_{\left[\frac{\tau_{j-1}}{L},\frac{\tau_{j}}{L}\right)}(\alpha)$ selects the interval $\left[\frac{\tau_{j-1}}{L},\frac{\tau_{j}}{L}\right)$, whose image is the $j$-th edge connecting $V_j$ and $V_{j+1}$

This parametrization defines a bijection between the unit interval $[0,1]$ and the triangle contour - which I denote as $\partial T =\{\psi(\alpha)\}_{\alpha \in [0,1]}$.
I would like to show that if $\alpha$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ then $z=\psi(\alpha)$ has a distribution that is uniform over the triangle perimeter $\partial T$. In other words, I want to show that the probability measure
\begin{equation*}\mathbb{P}(S)\triangleq\textrm{Prob}(z\in S) =
\textrm{Prob}(z\in S\cap \partial T)\end{equation*}
is given by
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(S)
=\frac{\textrm{length}(z\in S\cap \partial T)}{\textrm{length}(\partial T)}\end{equation*}
My attempt
Since $\partial T$ is a null measure set (i.e. has null area), the distribution of $z$ cannot be expressed by a probability density. Hence, the proof has to be carried out in terms of the probability measure $\mathbb{P}(S)$. Since $\psi(\alpha)$ is invertible over $z\in\partial T$, holds the following (if I'm not mistaken)
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(S)&=\textrm{Prob}(\psi^{-1}(z)\in \psi^{-1}(S\cap \partial T))=\int_{\psi^{-1}(S\cap\partial T)} p_\alpha(\alpha)\text{ d}\alpha
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
where $p_\alpha(\alpha)=1_{[0,1]}(\alpha)$ is the uniform PDF of $\alpha$. Thus,
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(S)&= \int_{\psi^{-1}(S\cap\partial T)\cap [0,1]} \text{ d}\alpha=
\int_{\psi^{-1}(S\cap\partial T)\cap \psi^{-1}(\partial T)} \text{ d}\alpha\\
&=\int_{\psi^{-1}(S\cap\partial T\cap\partial T)} \text{ d}\alpha=\int_{\psi^{-1}(S\cap\partial T)} \text{ d}\alpha=\textrm{length}(\psi^{-1}(S\cap \partial T))
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
Now, we can introduce the unitary normalizing factor
\begin{equation*}
\int_{[0,1]} \text{d}\alpha = \int_{\psi^{-1}(\partial T)} \text{d}\alpha=\textrm{length}(\psi^{-1}(\partial T))
\end{equation*}
obtaining
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(S)=\frac{\textrm{length}(\psi^{-1}(S\cap \partial T))}{\textrm{length}(\psi^{-1}(\partial T))}
\end{equation*}
Now, the particular parametrization that I propose has the following property. Let $J_\psi\triangleq \frac{\text{d}\psi}{\text{d}\alpha}$ be the $2\times 1$ Jacobian of $\psi(\alpha)$, then after some simple algebra it turns out that the Gramian "stretching factor"
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{J_\psi {}' J_\psi}=\left\lVert \frac{\text{d}\psi}{\text{d}\alpha} \right\rVert
\end{equation*}
gets the constant value $L$ for any $\alpha \in [0,1]$. This means that the length of any set $\ell\ \subseteq [0,1]$ is scaled by a factor $L$ whenever is mapped according $\psi$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}\textrm{length}(\psi(\ell))=L\,\textrm{length}(\ell)\end{equation*}
In the very same way, for any $\mathcal{L} \subseteq \partial P$ holds
\begin{equation*}\textrm{length}(\psi^{-1}(\mathcal{L}))=\frac{\textrm{length}(\mathcal{L})}{L}\end{equation*}
which yields to the conclusion
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(S)=\frac{\textrm{length}(S\cap \partial T)/L}{\textrm{length}(\partial T)/L}=
\frac{\textrm{length}(S\cap \partial T)}{\textrm{length}(\partial T)}
\end{equation*}
Remark
I'm not sure if my proof is formally correct because I'm not an expert in real analysis and measure theory. I think that the major issue with my proof is that it is not clear the meaning of the measure "$\textrm{length}(\mathcal{L})$" on $\mathbb{R}^2$. On $\mathbb{R}$, the measure "$\textrm{length}(\ell)$" is the Lebesgue one
\begin{equation*}\textrm{length}(\ell)\triangleq\int_\ell \text{d}\alpha \end{equation*}
On $\mathbb{R}^2$, the measure "$\textrm{length}(\mathcal{L})$", where $\mathcal{L}=\psi(\ell)$ for some $\ell\subseteq[0,1]$, is
\begin{equation}\textrm{length}(\mathcal{L})\triangleq\int_{\psi^{-1}(\mathcal{L})} \left\lVert \frac{\text{d}\psi}{\text{d}\alpha}\right\rVert \text{ d}\alpha\end{equation}
I never seen anything like that, so I hope that the expression above makes sense and is formally correct.
Questions
Thus my questions are:

Is my conclusion correct?
Given that my conclusion is correct, is my proof formally correct?

I hope there are no logical loopholes in my reasoning.
